# What does the end part of the Tales titles mean?

Tags: tales-series

Just going by the "Mothership" titles of the *Tales* series

- Tales of Phantasia
- Tales of Destiny
- Tales of Eternia
- Tales of Symphonia<sup>*****</sup>
- Tales of Rebirth<sup>*****</sup>
- Tales of Legendia
- Tales of the Abyss
- Tales of Innocence<sup>*****</sup>
- Tales of Vesperia<sup>*****</sup>
- Tales of Hearts<sup>*****</sup>
- Tales of Graces
- Tales of Xillia<sup>*****</sup>
- Tales of Zestiria<sup>*****</sup>
- Tales of Berseria<sup>*****</sup>

what does the end part represent in them?

I know that with Hearts R and Graces F, the R stands for Remake or Re-imagination and the F stands for "Future" because of Graces' extra content

> There are also terms that are used in remakes or ports of games: "R" stands for "remake" or "Re-imagination" (as in Hearts R), while "F" in Graces f stood for "future", in reference to the game's extra story content.

[Tales (Video Games Series) > Terminology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_(video_game_series)#Terminology)

but this doesn't explain what Hearts or Graces means in regards to the game. and i know it can't be worlds because

- Eternia is set on Inferia and Celestia
- The Abyss is set on Auldrant
- Zestiria and Berseria are on the same world just different eras

---

<sub>*: i have not played these yet so it may actually be obvious if i was to play them but for completeness i ask about them anyway</sub>

Comment: It's just a name. They didn't want to name them all "Tales of Destiny n"

Comment: @pboss3010 but Tales of Destiny was the 2nd released game after Phantasia in Japan and naming them all Tales of Destiny was exactly what the US was going to do when they renamed Tales of Eternia to Tales of Destiny 2 (before the actual Tales of Destiny 2 was released for the PS2)

Comment: Right, Tales of Graces and Tales of Hearts don't really mean anything specific. They are just entries in the "Tales of" series.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometimes there is a connection between the title and the "Characteristic Genre Name" of the game,

> which is essentially a short subtitle or phrase that outlines the game's overall theme. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_(video_game_series)#Terminology)

- Tales of Phantasia (*Legendary RPG*):
  The story was based on an unpublished Japanese novel called *Tale Phantasia* written by the game's programmer. Probably it is just a derivation of fantasy. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_of_Phantasia#Development)
- Tales of Destiny (*RPG of Destiny/RPG to Release Destiny*):
  It refers to the preordained meetings between the characters and their Swordians as they pursue their destiny. [Source](http://aselia.wikia.com/wiki/Tales_of_Destiny)
- Tales of Eternia (*RPG of Eternity and Bonds*):
  Derived from Eternity it is the name given to the world network in Tales of Eternia. It is a universal-like plane comprised of the worlds of Inferia and Celestia. [Source](http://aselia.wikia.com/wiki/Eternia_(world))
- Tales of Symphonia (*To Resonate With You RPG*):
  A symphony can be described as being a composition of different elements which would tie into the main plot of the two worlds and the party's goal to reunite them as well as the resounding connection between everyone's hearts. [Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/tales/comments/28tl39/meaning_behind_the_titles/cieheku/)
- Tales of Rebirth (*RPG Where You Will Be Reborn*):
  The game's title "Rebirth", was meant to represent the rebirth and reconstruction of harmonious relations between different peoples. Not so much a physical rebirth as a spiritual/mental one. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_of_Rebirth)
- Tales of Legendia (*RPG Where Bonds Spin Legends*):
  The legends surrounding several ingame elements(Teriques, the Legacy, their connections to the Ferises). [Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/tales/comments/28tl39/meaning_behind_the_titles/cieheku/)
- Tales of the Abyss (*RPG to Discover the Meaning of Life*):
  There is a giant underground area called Qliphoth. It is a massive void that contains an ocean of deadly miasma and mud. [Source](http://aselia.wikia.com/wiki/Qliphoth)
- Tales of Innocence (*RPG to Tie Thoughts Together*):
  The game's title was inspired by the main character Luca's portrayal as an innocent young boy thrust into the world's troubles. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_of_Innocence#Development)
- Tales of Vesperia (*RPG to Enforce "Justice"*):
  Vesperia is the name of a star ingame after which the guild of the main characters *Brave Vesperia* was named. The name is derived from the Roman name for the evening star Venus/Vesper. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_of_Vesperia)
- Tales of Hearts (*RPG to Meet the Heart*):
  The game's central theme is the uniting of people's hearts to overcome strife and two of the main characters have Hearts as last name. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_of_Hearts)
- Tales of Graces (*RPG to Discover the Strength to Protect*):
  Unsure about this one.
- Tales of Xillia (*RPG of Unwavering Convictions/RPG where Choices Spin the Future*):
  Producer Hideo Baba says it’s derived from million and billion, in English. He wanted to have a huge number and started with "Xillion" which eventually was changed to Xillia. The significance is within a persons life there are many events and encounters with people. [Source](http://www.siliconera.com/2011/05/06/depending-on-which-character-you-pick-tales-of-xillia-opens-in-two-different-ways/)
- Tales of Zestiria (*RPG of Passion that Illuminates the World*):
  Derived from *Zest* standing for the passion of the characters. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_of_Zestiria#Development)
- Tales of Berseria (*RPG of Discovering your Own Reason to Live*):
  The main theme of Tales of Berseria is the conflict between emotion and reason, with main character Velvet being the incarnation of emotion and rage. This theme is represented in the game's title, which stems from the term "Berserker", legendary warriors who were imbued with uncontrollable power. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_of_Berseria)
- Tales of Arise (*Telling the Dawn of the Heart RPG******): "Arise" was the internal codename used during development to signify the revitalization of the series using new technologies. It is also linked to the game's story, where the main characters rise up to overthrow their oppressors. [Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20190613115244/https://www.famitsu.com/news/201906/13177821.html)

Main source is [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/tales/comments/28tl39/meaning_behind_the_titles/cieheku/) reddit thread.

<sub>*: The english wikipedia lists the characteristic name as *RPG of Challenging the Fate That Binds You*. All other sources I found use the other name.</sub>